# Pass value to closure?

Tags: ios, swift, block

I want to do extra logic after last item was processed, but terminal show that `i` has always the same value as `c`. Any idea how to pass the loop variable in?

```
let c = a.count
for var i=0; i<c; i++ {

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {

        // ..

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            println("i \(i) c \(c)")
            if i == c-1 {

                // extra stuff would come here
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Closures capture variables fro their outer scope, therefore this code should be fine. Please provide where you initialize 'c'.

Comment: This is bound to hit a threading limit if the value of 'c' is too high...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can capture the value of `i` explicitly with a *capture list* `[i]`
in the closure, then you don't need to copy it to a separate variable.
Example:

```
let c = 5
for var i=0; i<c; i++ {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {
        [i] in   // <===== Capture list
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 

            println("i \(i) c \(c)")
        })
    })
}
```

Output:

```
i 0 c 5
i 1 c 5
i 2 c 5
i 3 c 5
i 4 c 5
```

Answer (score 7):

By the time your closure is executed, the for loop has already finished and `i` = `c`. You need an auxiliary variable inside the for loop:

```
let c = a.count
for var i=0; i<c; i++ {
    let k = i
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {

        // ..

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            println("k \(k) c \(c)")
            if k == c-1 {

                // extra stuff would come here
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a variable (not the iteration variable) to get the correct scope, e.g.

```
for var _i=0; _i<c; _i++ {
   let i = _i
   dispatch_async(...
```