# Variables becoming 0 after passing into DispatchQueue (works in Simulator. 0 in actual device)

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

There something wrong w/ the code that variables (workout time in seconds) are not getting passed into the GCD function call. But the  `workoutStartDateTime`  gets passed w no issues. Here's the code that I'm using.

```
  var seconds: Int = 0
  var workoutStartDateTime: Date?


  func finishWorkout() {
    print("0 FinishWorkout:\(seconds) workoutStartDateTime:\(workoutStartDateTime)")
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async { [self] in
      print("1 FinishWorkout:\(self.seconds) workoutStartDateTime:\(workoutStartDateTime)")
      TCXfuncs.writeTCX(workoutStartDateTime: workoutStartDateTime!, seconds: seconds)
      
    }
```

This is what gets printed out

```
0 FinishWorkout:3 workoutStartDateTime:Optional(2021-01-28 03:05:29 +0000)
1 FinishWorkout:0 workoutStartDateTime:Optional(2021-01-28 03:05:29 +0000)
// I also placed a print statement into the TCXFunc function to verify.
TCXExportFunction seconds:0
```

The odd thing is, when I run it in the simulator, it works. The number of seconds get passed.

```
0 FinishWorkout:3 workoutStartDateTime:Optional(2021-01-28 03:05:29 +0000)
1 FinishWorkout:3 workoutStartDateTime:Optional(2021-01-28 03:05:29 +0000)
// I also placed a print statement into the TCXFunc function to verify.
TCXExportFunction seconds:3
```

***Edit: (and solution)***

After many tries and SO/Googles, I found this SO --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31566063/14414215 and using this *works*. Now the question would be **Why**

```
  func finishWorkout() {
    let mySec = seconds
    print("0 FinishWorkout:\(seconds) mySec:\(mySec) workoutStartDateTime:\(workoutStartDateTime)")
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async { [self] in
      print("1 FinishWorkout:\(self.seconds) mySec:\(mySec)  workoutStartDateTime:\(workoutStartDateTime)")
      TCXfuncs.writeTCX(workoutStartDateTime: workoutStartDateTime!, seconds: mySec) // << Pass the "helper" variable
      
    }
```

This is the resultant output. You can see that the 119 becomes "0" in the 2nd print out with the "helper" variable gets it correct. Why.....?

```
0 FinishWorkout:119 mySec:119 workoutStartDateTime:Optional(2021-01-28 04:04:33 +0000)
1 FinishWorkout:0   mySec:119 workoutStartDateTime:Optional(2021-01-28 04:04:33 +0000)
// I also placed a print statement into the TCXFunc function to verify.

writeTCX Passed seconds:119 Date:2021-01-28 04:04:33 +0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a timing issue. The "dispatch.async()" call, means "do this somewhere in the future". This might be very soon (micro seconds) or even very late (milli seconds), but there might be other parts of your app, which resets the "seconds" meanwhile.

When you "save" the current content into a local variable BEFORE you submit the dispatch call, you have this value available, whenever the dispatch item will come to work.

Comment: You are absolutely Right. I just re-checked the code and commented out the part where I was reset-ting everything to get ready for the next workout (since I already called ```finishWorkout```)  and the value gets passed w/o issues.

Comment: Tho the odd thing is of course, this behaviour is not seen when running it on the simulator. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Glad it helped you. And Yes, this timing issues are depending on so many circumstances that even a different hardware (simulator) can change the outcome. Simulators on „good“ laptops are sometimes faster that „real“ mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

And one general hint: There is an „iron law“ ... never  ever handle a variable in different queues ... or only sometimes.. the side effects are too complex and may cause problems in future releases ..